# Java - The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable

Tags: java, getter-setter

I'm trying to make a small program that locates different cities as my first Java project.

I want to access the variables of my class 'GPS' from the class 'City' but I keep getting this error: The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable. Anyone can explain to me what am I am doing wrong here and how to avoid such mistake in the future?

```
public class Gps {
  private int x;
  private int y;
  private int z;

   public int getX() {
    return this.x; 
   }

   public int getY() {
    return this.y; 
   }

   public int getZ() {
    return this.z; 
   }
}
```

(I want to leave the variables as private)

And this class 'Citiy' should have the coordinates:

```
class City {
  Gps where;

   Location(int x, int y, int z) {
     where.getX() = x;
     where.getY() = y;    //The Error Here
     where.getZ() = z;
   }
}
```

Comment: The `int`s are private. Create setters: `setX(int x) {this.x = x;}` and then use `where.setX(x);` Also, your class won't compile anyways

Comment: You need to use a Setter to change private members of `Gps`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error speaks for itself: you cannot assign a value to something that is not a field or a variable. Getters are for *getting* values stored in the class. Java uses *setters* to deal with storing the values back:

```
public int getX() {
    return x; 
}
public void setX(int x) {
    this.x = x;
}
```

Now you can set values by invoking the setter:

```
City(int x, int y, int z) {
    where.setX(x);
    ...
}
```

However, this solution is not ideal, because it makes `Gps` *mutable*. You can keep it immutable by adding a constructor:

```
public Gps(int x, int y, int z) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
}
```

Now `City` can set `where` in one shot:

```
City(int x, int y, int z) {
    where = new Gps(x, y, z);
}
```

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you for the help. May I ask one last question, what if I want to call the x of GPS through a Getter inside City? :)

Comment: @Baldr You have access to getters the usual way - e.g. `public int getX() {return where.getX();}` Another approach is to publish `where` - e.g. `public Gps getWhere() {return where;}` The callers will get X like this: `myCity.getWhere().getX()`

Answer (score 2):

Don't set properties with getter. It should be done like that:

```
public class Gps {
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int z;

    public int getX() {
        return this.x; 
    }

    public int getY() {
        return this.y; 
    }

    public int getZ() {
        return this.z; 
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void setZ(int z) {
        this.z = z;
    }
}


class City {
    Gps where;

    City(int x, int y, int z) {
       this.where = new Gps();
       where.setX(x);
       where.setY(y);
       where.setZ(z);
    }
}
```